# Why is my set accessor not firing in my C# Code First Property?

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-web-api

We have an Oracle Package that returns a column built from a case statement.
The column returns 0 or 1 since Oracle does not support a Boolean.

Something like:

```
CASE WHEN EXISTS
   SELECT somecolumn from table
   WHERE somecondition Then 1
   ELSE 0
END AS IcAssignedToGrant
```

When we try to fill a code first Object with the mapped column being a bool, we get a message from .Net saying it can't convert a type decimal to a type bool.

So I'm trying something like this (in Web API BTW):

```
public class NonCompetingRenewalResponse
{
    private object _icAssignedToGrant;

    public decimal? ApplId { get; set; }
    public decimal ContactPIProfileId { get; set; }
    public string PiNameList { get; set; }
    public string ProgramClassCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BudgetStartDate { get; set; }
    public string AprStatus { get; set; }
    public string FullGrantNum { get; set; }
    public string ProjectTitle { get; set; }
    public string PmChecklistStatusCode { get; set; }
    public string GmChecklistStatusCode { get; set; }

    public object IcAssignedToGrant
    {
        get
        {
            return _icAssignedToGrant;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((int)value == 1)
            {
                _icAssignedToGrant = true;
            }
            else
            {
                _icAssignedToGrant = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

But the set accessor never gets fired.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Or is there someway to cast the incoming decimal to the property as a bool from a WEB API action filter somehow?

I also tried this but OnPropertyChanged also does not fire:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Nete.Ireport.Models.ViewModels
{
public class NonCompetingRenewalResponse : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Declare the event
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }


    private object _icAssignedToGrant;

    public decimal? ApplId { get; set; }
    public decimal ContactPIProfileId { get; set; }
    public string PiNameList { get; set; }
    public string ProgramClassCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BudgetStartDate { get; set; }
    public string AprStatus { get; set; }
    public string FullGrantNum { get; set; }
    public string ProjectTitle { get; set; }
    public string PmChecklistStatusCode { get; set; }
    public string GmChecklistStatusCode { get; set; }

    public object IcAssignedToGrant
    {
        get
        {
            return _icAssignedToGrant;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((int)value == 1)
            {
                _icAssignedToGrant = true;
                OnPropertyChanged("IcAssignedToGrant");

            }
            else
            {
                _icAssignedToGrant = false;
                OnPropertyChanged("IcAssignedToGrant");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You don't show the sql code, but try using the CAST function to caste to a integer or number(1) or some other relevant data type.

Comment: I already return a 1 or 0.
Also I tried to CAST the CASE statement as a column to int.
Does anyone know how to finish the Observable pattern above?